# jquery validation with json verification

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I need help in this code, I am trying to implement a request via url with the `$ get.Json` method in the additional jquery validate method, can anyone help me?

```js
$(function(){
  $.validator.addMethod('cep', function(val) {

    var cep = val.replace(/\D/g, '');
    //Expressão regular para validar o CEP.
    var validacep = /^[0-9]{8}$/;

    //Valida o formato do CEP.
    if (validacep.test(cep)) {
        //Consulta o webservice viacep.com.br/
        $.getJSON("https://viacep.com.br/ws/" + cep + "/json/?callback=?", function(dados) {
            if (!("erro" in dados)) {
                return true;
            } //end if.
            else {
                //CEP pesquisado não foi encontrado.
                return false
            }
        });
    } //end if.
    else {
        //cep é inválido.
        return false;
    }
}, 'Cep invalido');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
    <html>
      <body>
        <form>
          <label>Zip Brasil</label>
          <br>
          <input type="text" id="zip" value="" name="zip" required>
          <button>send</button>
        </form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hello ! Welcome to SO, can you state your problem? What is wrong with your code and where do you need help ?

Comment: Hello thanks for your help, what happens is that it always returns me the error message "Cep invalido", being that the zip is valid.

Comment: Example the zip 00000000 does not exist and still passes the validation ...

Comment: @Stoogy help-me

Comment: Where is your `.validate()` method?  How can we help when you show an incomplete demo?

Comment: You should not mix versions.  If you use jQuery Validate version 1.17, then you should only use Additional Methods version 1.17

Comment: You cannot use a default `<button>` without making it a `type="submit"`.